# How to Center RecyclerView with GridLayout (spanCount = 2)?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, cardview

So I'm experimenting with `RecyclerView`.

This is my activity_main...

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activityMain_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:spanCount="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        cardView()
    }

    private fun cardView() {
        val adapterReference = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
        activityMain_recyclerView.adapter = adapterReference
       // activityMain_recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)

        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())
        adapterReference.add(CardViewGroup())

    }
}

class CardViewGroup() : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.layout_card_view
    }

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }

}
```

It currently looks like this...

[image]

I was hoping to make it look like...

[image]

Comment: Update your question with layout_card_view code

Comment: Can you please add the code of the layout_card_view ? I think you have positioned the view wrongly there.

Comment: @FilipSollár I just did, and it still doesnt work. I also tried adding LinearLayout as a parent of the cardview child and it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved this problem.**

steps to follow for best results in recyclerView experience

- Make  `<CardView>` as the parent for your layout, and set its dimensions as...

  > `layout_width="match_parent"`
  >
  > `layout_height="wrap_content"`
  >
  > `layout_margin="16dp"` try and remove this after building it to see the difference.
- Make `<ConstraintLayout>` as the container inside the `<CardView>` parent. and set its dimensions as...

  > `layout_width="match_parent"`
  >
  > `layout_height="wrap_content"`

P.s. Don't forget to add contrast to your Cardview background and recyclerView background to clearly see the difference

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the layout_card_view.xml but i think this will work

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your layout_card_view.xml

Hope it helps

Comment: It didnt work. Is it possible that GridLayoutManger isnt code for this? Should i use GridView instead?

Comment: Try to Wrap CardView with Relative Layout and set the android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: Can you share your layout_card_view.xml

Comment: Yes, i actually did when i replied to you. Still looking for a solution tho. Also looking up how to use BaseAdapters.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this

[image: Grid view]

by using this code for layout_card_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#6060ff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello world!"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what was your activity_main.xml file? Can i see?

Comment: Tried it, it works, thanks! But i have a concern that this might result in the spacing having an effect of an onSetClickListener